# Write data to excel and change sheet name using ActiveX--Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I need to export data to excel sheet with a specific name using Activex. Here is what I did: First i export the data to excel in first for loop and then modify the names of the sheet using second for loop. Can it be done even in one single for loop? I think there should be another better idea. 
**Note: The size of the data varies.**

```
try
    filename = fullfile(pwd,'example.xlsx');
    for i=1:5
        xlswrite(filename,[1 2;3 4]*i,i);
    end
    for i = 1:5
        myExcel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
        excelWorkBook = myExcel.Workbooks.Open(filename,0,false);
        excelWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(i).Name = ['new_sheet_' num2str(i)]; 
        excelWorkBook.Save;
        excelWorkBook.Close;
        myExcel.Quit;
    end

catch
    % Disp Error message.....
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fratyx's answer is the simplest to implement, but a bit of knowledge of the Excel Object Model goes a long way, so here's how to implement your solution with ActiveX in one loop:

```
     e = actxserver('excel.application');
     w = e.Application.Workbooks.Add();
     numnewsheets = 4;
     for i = 1:numnewsheets
         w.Worksheets.Add([],w.Sheets.Item(w.Sheets.Count),1);
         w.Worksheets.Item(i).Name = ['new_sheet_' num2str(i)];
         w.Worksheets.Item(i).Cells.Range('A1:B2').Value = [1 2;3 4];
     end
     w.SaveAs(filename)
     w.Close
     e.Quit
     e.delete
```

To calculate the range required for the size of your data, you will have to open file "xlswrite" and copy out the sub-function "calcrange".

Comment: The range and the number of sheets are fixed in this case. How can I make it flexible. The size of the data varies.

Answer (score 4):

The `xlswrite` function also accepts a string as `sheet` parameter. So just replace your call by this one:

```
xlswrite(filename,[1 2;3 4]*i,['new_sheet_' num2str(i)]);
```